# Magento2 : Block Frontend area access

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have a headless Magento2 instance i.e magento serves as backend for an IOS app , So i want to disable access to frontend website and keep the access to REST APIs . I am using ngnix and magento 2.2.3 community .

I was going to implement a plugin to frontcontoller action to redirect to some external , is this the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "**plugin to frontcontoller action to redirect to some external**" is  best solution .

In future,if you require then you can access your frontend also.

This is simplest and efficient process to prevent the frontend to access.